# How to fix "type parameter to bare `Fn` trait must be a tuple" from detour-rs?

Tags: rust

When compiling a project, it throws errors from the detour-rs crate:

```
Compiling detour v0.8.0 (https://github.com/darfink/detour-rs?rev=3b6f17a#3b6f17a8)
error[E0059]: type parameter to bare `Fn` trait must be a tuple
   --> C:\Users\Станислав\.cargo\git\checkouts\detour-rs-497fa4e2739f3073\3b6f17a\src\detours\statik.rs:106:8
    |
106 |     D: Fn<T::Arguments, Output = T::Output> + Send + 'static,
    |        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ the trait `Tuple` is not implemented for `<T as Function>::Arguments`
    |
note: required by a bound in `Fn`
help: consider further restricting the associated type
    |
106 |     D: Fn<T::Arguments, Output = T::Output> + Send + 'static, <T as Function>::Arguments: Tuple
    |                                                             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

error[E0059]: type parameter to bare `Fn` trait must be a tuple
   --> C:\Users\Станислав\.cargo\git\checkouts\detour-rs-497fa4e2739f3073\3b6f17a\src\detours\statik.rs:157:8
    |
157 |     C: Fn<T::Arguments, Output = T::Output> + Send + 'static,
    |        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ the trait `Tuple` is not implemented for `<T as Function>::Arguments`
    |
note: required by a bound in `Fn`
help: consider further restricting the associated type
    |
157 |     C: Fn<T::Arguments, Output = T::Output> + Send + 'static, <T as Function>::Arguments: Tuple
    |                                                             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0059`.
error: could not compile `detour` due to 2 previous errors
warning: build failed, waiting for other jobs to finish...
```

I tried changing the version of detour-rs, but that didn't help. How to fix it?

Answer (score 2):

`detour` relies on using nightly Rust features to implement the `static_detour!` macro.

Nightly features are unstable and subject to change without warning - and in this case, [it looks like that is what's happened](https://github.com/darfink/detour-rs/issues/39).

Your options are:

- If you are not using `static_detour!`, disable the [default feature flags](https://github.com/darfink/detour-rs/blob/master/Cargo.toml#L29-L32) of the crate to avoid including this in the build.

  - `detour = { version = "0.8", default-features = false }`
- Wait for the crate to update to support the latest nightly (though note that `detour` hasn't had commits since 2021).

  - Or alternatively, fork the crate and do the update yourself.
- Downgrade to an earlier nightly version of Rust.

Answer (score 0):

Commands for downgrading rust toolchain that helped me with this problem

```
rustup toolchain install nightly-2022-10-29-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc
rustup default nightly-2022-10-29-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc
```

Comment: I'd recommend just using `nightly-2022-10-29` (assuming the code compiles with that one) without the `-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc`.This way the command also works for people on linux / macos. I'd also maybe not recommend setting it as the default and instead creating a `rust-toolchain` file on the project root with the contents ``nightly-2022-10-29``, which would force that specific version on the project.